# Scrolling a ScrollViewer without steps/gaps when using the mouse

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app, scrollviewer, windows-10-universal

Using mouse interaction, when dragging the ScrollBar of a ScrollViewer horizontally, the content of the ScrollViewer is scrolled in small steps. If the app is run with touch interaction scrolling is smooth without any steps / gaps. How can I scroll using the mouse without steps / gaps as it is done with touch interaction?

Desktop:
[image]

Mouse:
[image]

Comment: `ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"`, have you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to hide the ScrollBar of the ScrollViewer and use the click and drag mouse events directly. WaveformScroller is the ScrollViewer. WaveformCanvas is the scrolled control.

```
Vector2 lastDragPoint;
bool pointerPressed;

WaveformCanvas.PointerPressed += (sender, args) =>
{
        WaveformCanvas.CapturePointer(args.Pointer);
        lastDragPoint = args.GetCurrentPoint((UIElement)sender).Position.ToVector2();
        pointerPressed = true;
};

WaveformCanvas.PointerMoved += (sender, args) =>
{
    if (pointerPressed)
    {
        var newDragPoint = args.GetCurrentPoint((UIElement)sender).Position.ToVector2();
        var deltaX = newDragPoint.X - lastDragPoint.X;
        var newOffset = WaveformScroller.HorizontalOffset - deltaX;
        WaveformScroller.HorizontalOffset = WaveformScroller.HorizontalOffset - deltaX;
    }
};

WaveformCanvas.PointerReleased += (sender, args) =>
{
    pointerPressed = false;
    WaveformCanvas.ReleasePointerCapture(args.Pointer);
};
```